# Input fields drop down MM/YY

Tags: html, css

I am trying to edit a plugin field to use a drop down Expiry but need little bit of help. Here is what I have so far:

```
 function payment_fields()
      {
         if ( $this->description ) 
            echo wpautop(wptexturize($this->description));
            echo '<label style="margin-right:46px; line-height:40px;">Credit Card Number:</label> <input type="text" name="aim_credircard" /><br/>';
            echo '<label style="margin-right:30px; line-height:40px;">Credit Card Expiry (MM/YY) :</label> <input type="text"  style="width:50px;" name="aim_ccexpdate" maxlength="4" /><br/>';
            echo '<label style="margin-right:89px; line-height:40px;">CVV :</label> <input type="text" name="aim_ccvnumber"  maxlength=4 style="width:40px;" /><br/>';
      }
```

I want to be able to edit the following code to reflect a drop down month and year without creating a problem for the submission the front end and SELECT and SUBMIT the way it is right now.

```
 echo '<label style="margin-right:30px; line-height:40px;">Credit Card Expiry (MM/YY) :</label> <input type="text"  style="width:50px;" name="aim_ccexpdate" maxlength="4" /><br/>';
```

Thank you

Comment: So you want two fields, one for MM and one for YY but when they're submitted they still post as one parameter named `aim_ccexpdate`?

Comment: How do I close this thread? I no longer need help with this issue. Thanks a lot